# Share across network to Windows users

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I have a folder I want to share with a couple windows users on the network.

I am using ubuntu 10.4

When I right click a folder I go to "Sharing Options"

There are 3 check boxes. If I check the first 2 which are "share this folder" and "Allow others to create and delete files in this folder" I can now *see* this folder on the network from my pc.

I cannot access it though, it asks for a username and password (I never set one up so I don't even know what credentials it wants.)

I don't want to have to log in, I just want to be able to go right in.

So If I check the third box, which is "guest access" I can now access the folder from my pc. But so can everyone else on the network. I just want myself and a couple other pc users on the network to be able to access it.

I do not see anyplace where I can specify what users on the network have permission to access it? How do I do that?

---

### update

When I entered my user name and password for the linux machine, it gave me this error message:

> \LINUX-SERVER\saga_repo is not
> accessible. You might not have
> permission to use this network
> resource. Contact the administrator of
> this server to find out if you have
> access permissions.
>
> Multiple connections to a server or
> shared resource by the same user,
> using more than one user name, are not
> allowed. Disconnect all previous
> connections to the server or shared
> resource and try again.

I noticed that when type in my username it defaults to @MY-DOMAIN so I also tried myuser@linux-server but still got the same message.

Also the domain administrator (who knows nothing about linux) told me that the linux machine is not a part of the domain (even though I can see it when I go to My Network Places from my windows machine). I don't know if that means anything.

I also tried created a new user on ubuntu to try to log in with and got the same message. I tried to log in with my user and the new user from a workers machine and I couldn't get in from there either but I just got an "access denied" dialog everytime on his machine.

Is there possibly another step I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way (in my opinion) to share files across a local network with Windows machines is to use a program I've written called [NitroShare](https://web.archive.org/web/20160523154747/https://nitroshare.net/downloads/). All you need to do is install the application on each of the machines. Then you can simply drag-and-drop files.

**Installing on Ubuntu**

Simply open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install nitroshare
```

**Installing on Windows**

Simply download and run the installer below:

https://launchpad.net/nitroshare/0.2/0.2/+download/nitroshare_0.2_win32.exe

**Transferring files**

Once you have the application installed on each machine, you should see a small box on each desktop:

[image]

[image]

Simply drag a file on to the box to send it to another machine. That's it.

Comment: Good but its not solution for this problem. Problem here is sharing folder from another comp so we can access files all the time.

Comment: i love your application and am glad to see you on askubuntu! but i have some problems in xfce (although i am not sure this is related to the OS or DE). could you take a look at [my question](http://askubuntu.com/q/304361/47206)?

Answer (score 3):

The username and password it asks for should be **your** username and password on the local machine.  It's as simple as that.

For instance, if your username in Ubuntu is `john` and your password is `iloveubuntu`, then you should enter those two to access your files from any computer.

If you want others to be able to access a shared directory, just create a user for them on the local machine, and they should be able to access it using their own username and password too. You probably need to set the **Allow others to create and delete files in this folder** to let them edit the files, but this is not necessary for just sharing your files with them.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried what you said but it did not work for me. Please see my update to my question.

Comment: Username on which machine?  The Windows computer that's trying to access the files, or the Ubuntu computer that's sharing them?