# Is Nitroshare transfer limited to a certain file size?

Tags: files, xfce, transfer, crossplatform, nitroshare

I have recently seen [Nitroshare](http://nitroshare.net/downloads) promoted on this site and have installed it in Ubuntu (Xubuntu 12.10) and Win7.

I was able to transfer files but only up to a certain size. I have not tested with very large files, up to 60 MB it worked, but an archive of about 360 MB was not successfully transferred. While a folder of 128MB was sent, a zip archive of the same folder was not, crashing the sending application.

I see here that in fact the free version is the lite one, with clear limitations.

[image]

What does that mean exactly? I guess that the bandwidth is limited here, not the file size to be transferred.

I see the limitation considered [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/nitroshare/+question/204725) as a bug, in relation to a limit representing "anything larger than about one-half the amount of memory your computer has". But if that's the RAM, even the bugged limit is far larger than what I've experienced.

What is the real limit - so that I would not bother transferring something that is too large ?

Also, I do not see any progress bar in the "share box" on the desktop as supposed and illustrated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/160739/47206), not even when the transfer works .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### Update:
>
> As of [NitroShare 0.3.0](http://nitroshare.net/downloads) (released March 21, 2015), this limitation no longer applies. NitroShare can now transfer files of any size. It also displays transfer progress on both the sending and receiving device.

---

> I was able to transfer files but only up to a certain size.

This is indeed a limitation of the current stable version (0.2).

> I see here that in fact the free version is the lite one, with clear limitations.

Actually, your screenshot is from the new website being prepared for NitroShare 0.3, which has not yet been released. You can safely ignore anything stated there when referring to NitroShare 0.2, which does not artificially impose any limitation on file size.

> But if that's the RAM, even the bugged limit is far larger than what I've experienced.

The underlying problem here is that NitroShare 0.2 loads each file into memory when transferring it over the network - so the size of the file is limited by the amount of available memory to the application. And that number depends on quite a few variables.

> Also, I do not see any progress bar in the "share box" on the desktop as supposed and illustrated here, not even when the transfer works.

If I remember correctly, NitroShare only displays progress on the machine sending the files. If you are not seeing progress on either machine, then that's a bug.

Comment: `This is indeed a limitation of the current stable version (0.2)` - is it possible to know the limitation? i have one 1GB RAM and one 4GB RAM computers and was not able to transfer above 100 MB file

Comment: @cipricus: Unfortunately not. The good news is that the new version of NitroShare will completely eliminate this restriction since it reads small chunks of the file at a time. This will allow a PC with very little RAM to transfer files that are several GB in size.

Comment: i'll use [the alternatives that i've found](http://askubuntu.com/q/304362/47206) until then :) - thank you for opening my interest on the matter