# Are there other applications beside Nitroshare to send files between computers on the same LAN?

Tags: transfer, crossplatform, nitroshare

I have tried [Nitroshare](http://nitroshare.net/downloads) and had appreciated the simple way to install in order to transfer files between my devices with different OS-es. But, given the fact that Nitroshare has some bug/limitation (as reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/304361/47206)) I would like to know if there are other such programs available at a comparable level of required skills.

Comment: **Note:** As of [NitroShare 0.3.0](https://launchpad.net/nitroshare/0.3/0.3.0), this limitation no longer applies. NitroShare can now transfer files of any size.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/310180/62483

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**TransferOnLAN**](http://code.google.com/p/transfer-on-lan/downloads/list) is a similar tool, based on Java.

It works in Linux (extract archive and execute the TransferOnLAN.sh file) and in Windows. Once opened on all machines, all should be visible.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Restart the program on all machines when others are not visible as they should.

[image]

[image]

Separate files can be selected and sent together and will appear as one package as in the images above. Sending a second file while another is in progress will create a waiting list.

---

[**Dukto**](http://www.msec.it/blog/?page_id=11) is very impressive and with a very elegant Metro style. It has support for many systems and devices - look for more info at that page.

In Ubuntu/Xfce 12.10 I have selected "Grab binary packages directly" and installed the 12.04 deb with no problems.

[image]

[image]

Files are automatically accepted.

Selected multiple files (or files in a folder sent as such) are listed as one package.

Sending a second package while another is in progress is not possible.

---

Incomplete files or with errors may result in error/impossible transfer in all these applications.